# How to execute a task after assembleRelease?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-crash-reporting

[Firebase-Crash has a new feature](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#uploading_proguard_mapping_files_with_gradle). You can upload your `mapping.txt` using a Gradle command: `./gradlew :app:firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping`.

I want to automate this process. I want to upload that `mapping.txt` file to Firebase as soon as I create a release apk.

How can I force Gradle to execute `firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping` after a succesful `assembleRelease`? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I didn't solve it yet. I'm using the @Doug Stevenson's solution but it's not exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

In general you can define a dependencies for the task using the `dependsOn` method.

For example:

```
task A << {
    println 'Hello from A'
}

task B << {
    println 'Hello from B'
}

B.dependsOn A
```

You will obtain

```
> gradle -q B
Hello from A
Hello from B
```

In your case you can specify:

```
firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping.dependsOn assembleRelease
```

Also you can use the `finalizedBy` method.

```
A.finalizedBy B
```

Note that :

- this will run `B` even if `A` failed.
- finalizedBy is marked as "incubating" which means that this is an experimental feature and its behavior can be changed in future releases.

Comment: With this solution I must run `./gradlew :app:firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping`. Am I right? I don't want to change the main task. I mean, I want to run `./gradlew :app:assembleRelease`.

Comment: You are right. There is another way as I know,but keep attention.

Comment: Instead of 
firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping.dependsOn assembleRelease
you need:
assembleRelease.dependsOn firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping

Answer (score 2):

```
project.tasks.whenTaskAdded { Task task ->
if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
    task.doLast {
        println("makeSystemSignature")
    }
    task.finalizedBy(makeSystemSignature)
}}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: As this answer uses, finalizedBy, not dependsOn, should be used if you want to always run a task after another.  The tricky part is that the task you want to call finalizedBy on doesn't exist and is auto added during the build, so directly referencing it will cause errors.  The answer is to wait until the task is added to configure the finalizedBy as this answer does.

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully at the chain of tasks that get executed when you target firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping:

```
...
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease
:app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:app:transformNative_libsWithStripDebugSymbolForRelease
:app:packageRelease
:app:assembleRelease
:app:firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping
```

See that firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping already depends on assembleRelease.  You don't need to force any additional dependencies for what you're trying to do - the dependency is already set up by the plugin, so that when you tell gradle to run that task, it will have already completed a release build.  If you always want to upload after a successful release build, simply target firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping instead of assembleRelease.

Answer (score 0):

One can define an external tool "generate signed APK and upload the ProGuard mapping file" - instead of the "generate signed APK" button, because the task `firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping` depends on `assembleRelease` and therefore will **always** execute it. the Firebase Plugins recently was updated to [1.1.0](https://bintray.com/firebase/gradle/com.google.firebase.firebase-plugins/1.1.0) ...

[image: Screenshot]

the result:

```
:mobile:assembleRelease
:mobile:firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping
Attempting to upload Proguard mapping file...
```

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle` do:

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.assembleRelease.finalizedBy {
        task postReleaseTask(type: Exec) {
            // Work
        }
    }
}
```

or in your case:

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.assembleRelease.finalizedBy firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping
}
```